# Trying to publish emails to firebase console

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

My Question is about trying to publish email to firebase console, and my chrome developer tools don't throw any errors. However, emails are not being displayed in the firebase console. Emails should be stored when clicked on submit from homepage.

HTML

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span> App</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button routerLink="/admin" mat-flat-button color="primary" id="Admin">Admin</button>

  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<br>
<br>
<form [formGroup]="this.userInfoService.form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="$key">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input formControlName="newEmail" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" >
        </div>


<div class="example-container">

  <br>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name">
  </mat-form-field>
  &nbsp;
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>
<h4>Instructions:</h4>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item>1. Please note that there is no time limit.</mat-list-item>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-list-item>2. It is mandatory to answer all the questions.</mat-list-item>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-list-item>3. You will have a chance to review before submitting.</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- <button routerLink="/question-page" mat-flat-button color="primary" id="start">Start</button> -->
  <input type="button"  routerLink="/question-page" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
</form>


<!-- <div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div> -->
```

Service File:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  emailList:AngularFireList<any>;

  form = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    newEmail: new FormControl('', Validators.required)

  });

  getEmail(){
    this.emailList = this.firebase.list('emails') ;
    return this.emailList.snapshotChanges();
  }

  insertEmail(email){
    this.emailList = this.firebase.list('emails');
    this.emailList.push({
      newEmail: email.newEmail
    });

  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {UserInfoService} from '../shared/user-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userInfoService: UserInfoService) { }
  submitted:boolean;
  formControls=this.userInfoService.form.controls;


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(){

    this.submitted = true;
    if(this.userInfoService.form.valid){
      if(this.userInfoService.form.get('$key').value == null) {
        this.userInfoService.insertEmail(this.userInfoService.form.value);
      this.submitted = false;
      }

    }
  }

}
```

XXXXXXX:NOTE: I'm only trying to read email XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX